# CPLEX dvar as condition

Tags: linear-programming, cplex, mixed-integer-programming

I have this problem while trying to find a solution for a resource constraint scheduling problem. Whenever I put dvar as a condition in a forall loop or if condition I have the error that states "Decision variable (or expression) "S" not allowed".

```
range activity = 1..16;
dvar float+ S[activity];

dvar float+ rd[jobs];

forall (i in activity)
 forall (t in T:S[i]<=t<=S[i]+D[i]) //boolean b 
        b[i][t]==1;

forall (t in T)
  forall (k in R)
    sum (i in activity)b[i][t]*V[i][k]<=Rk[k];//human resources constraint

  forall (j in jobs)
  forall (t in T:rd[j]<=t<=S[maxact[j]])//boolean y
  y[j][t]==1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common mistake. The code you are writing is *building* the model for cplex. The cplex variables in your (dvars, like your S) usually do not have a value until the model has been solved, so you *cannot* use their value during the model building process. You need to restructure your problem and you will probably need to use additional bool or int variables or indicator constraints inside your model.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answers were very useful.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
range activity = 1..16; 
dvar float+ S[activity];
range jobs=1..3; 
range T=1..3; 
range R=1..4;
dvar boolean b[activity][T]; 
dvar boolean y[jobs][T]; 
int D[activity];
int Rk[R]; int V[activity][R]; int maxact[j in jobs]=1;

dvar float+ rd[jobs];

subject to { 
 forall (i in activity)  
  forall (t in T) //boolean b 
     ((S[i]<=t) &&(t<=S[i]+D[i])) => (b[i][t]==1);

 forall (t in T)   forall (k in R)
  sum (i in activity)b[i][t]*V[i][k]<=Rk[k];//human resources constraint

   forall (j in jobs)   forall (t in T)//boolean y  
 ((rd[j]<=t) &&
 (t<=S[maxact[j]])) =>  (y[j][t]==1); 
}
```